# Changing an image source from a select value property

Tags: javascript, html-select

I'm trying to change an image source based on the value in a drop-down menu, but for some reason the code I'm using doesn't seem to work.

**html**

```
<select id="strapOptions">
<option value="black">Black Strap</option>
<option value="white">White Strap</option>
</select>
<button type="button" onclick="chooseStrapColour()">Apply Strap</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
function chooseStrapColour() {
var black = "images/straps/oxford-black.png"
var white = "images/straps/oxford-white.png"
var colourRange = document.getElementById("strapOptions").value;
document.getElementById("oxStrap").src = colourRange;
}
```

If I change the src = at the end of the 5th line to either 'black' or 'white' then it does change the image source url, so I suspect it's something in the 4th line that's broken it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you got `colourRange`, its value is just `"black"` or `"white"`, you need to use that to further decide the string to put to src, not that value:

```
function chooseStrapColour() {
   var black = "images/straps/oxford-black.png"
   var white = "images/straps/oxford-white.png"
   var colourRange = document.getElementById("strapOptions").value;
   var src = (colourRange === "white") ? white : black;
   document.getElementById("oxStrap").src = src;
}
```

Comment: Works a treat. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another option is just to append the color into the image src, like so

```js
function chooseStrapColour() {
var colourRange = document.getElementById("strapOptions").value;
document.getElementById("oxStrap").src = "images/straps/oxford-"+colourRange+".png";
}
```

```html
<select id="strapOptions">
<option value="black">Black Strap</option>
<option value="white">White Strap</option>
</select>
<button type="button" onclick="chooseStrapColour()">Apply Strap</button> 
<img src='' id='oxStrap'/>
```